# how to implement a method be the driver a private recursive routine

Tags: java

I am in the second part of my homework, where it asked us to: Implement reverse by having reverse be the driver for a private recursive routine. reverse will create a StringBuffer and pass it to the recursive routine.

Can someone explain what the question is exactly asking.

I have written the reverse method (first-part of my HW) as follow and it is right.

```
public static void reverse(int input) {
        if (input <= 0) {
            //System.out.print(" Enter positive input");
        } else {
            System.out.print(input % 10);
            reverse(input / 10);
        }
```

However, for the second part I did the following but I dont even understand the question properly and what it wants me to do. Can someone help me or gave me an example?

```
private void reverse(int input){

        }
```

Comment: Note: StringBuffer is an obsolete class. You can use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: What are you trying to reverse? Your mention of `StringBuffer` would suggest `String` content, yet your recursive method deals with primitive `int`s and recursively divides them by `10` until the exist condition...

Comment: "_Can someone explain what the question is exactly asking._" Your teacher .... they actually like to answer questions.

Comment: Questions such as this are something you should really clarify with your teacher. If that's the only information you've been given, the question is not clear and we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 2):

Well, its not clear at all so maybe you should ask your teacher

My interpretation is that theres should be a public reverse function that calls a private one, something like this

```
public Integer reverse(Integer toReverse) {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

  reverse(toReverse.toString(), buffer);

  return new Integer(buffer.toString());
}

private void reverse(String toReverse, StringBuffer buffer) {
  //reverse by appending to the buffer
  //this is the part of the homework you need to do
}
```

So maybe thats what they mean by "driver" but its still quite stupid, so, real answer: I'd ask your teacher what he meant

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'd say if I had to hazard a guess. If the previous questions were centered around reversing an integer, the introduction of `StringBuffer` is needlessly confusing.

Comment: I would say that too. Except that this is not mention you should pass the `String toReverse`. And the exit condition will be a pain...